# Distorted images when using GLSurfaceView for camera preview

Tags: android, image, opengl-es, camera, google-glass

I've got the problem, that when I try to use a `GLSurfaceView` to display the camera preview, the preview image ends up being totally distorted, but only if I choose a preview size of >= 1280x720. At lower resolutions (e.g. 960x720) everything is fine. Here is what the preview image looks like:

[image: distorted camera preview image]

I noticed this while I was trying to record a video stream from the camera, which works fine appart from the distorted images. So I tried to just show the camera preview using this code -> http://maninara.blogspot.co.at/2012/09/render-camera-preview-using-opengl-es.html

I noticed that as soon as the width gets larger than 1000px, the image ends up distorted, and also tried to use another image format, but that didn't help either. I'm running this on a Google Glass API 19.

Kindest regards,
Wolfram

Comment: With the Design of the UI is only 640 x 360, could it be a resolution limitation? I'm curious

Comment: This also happens if I don't display the video, but feed it into an encoder instead. Also, 960x720 works fine, and is far beyond the display resolution. I first thought it was the encoder's fault, because the resulting video looked the same when the camera preview size and the encoder image size did not match, but now there is only the camera and a GLSurfaceView. Furthermore, the preview works fine with resolutions up to 1080p when I set the camera preview to a normal SurfaceView instead.